# Length of $\mathfrak{m}$-torsion module

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring and $M$ is an $R$-module such that $\mathfrak{m}^tM=0$ for some non-negative integer $t$. Then the length of $M$ is finite.

Is that right?

Comment: Do you want may be $\mathfrak{m}$ to be finitely generated?  What about infinitely many copies of $R/\mathfrak{m}$ which is killed by $\mathfrak{m}$ but has infinite length?

Comment: $M$, not $\mathfrak{m}$, should be finitely generated to avoid Filippo's counterexample.

Comment: But then yes, if it is finitely generated there is a surjection $R^n \to M$.  But then $M$ is also a quotient of $R^n/\mathfrak{m}^t$, which is certainly of finitely length

Comment: A slightly different approach: under the hypotheses, $M$ is a module over the Artinian ring $A/\mathfrak{m}^tA$. Thus, $M$ is of finite length iff it is finitely generated.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I meant $M$....

Comment: Thank for your comments. In this case, $M$ is not finitely generated.